# Passing NSData Multiplayer GAme

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, multiplayer

I want to pass an array from one player to another player:

This is how I create it:

```
NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&_spieleScreenshots length:sizeof(_spieleScreenshots)];
```

`NSData. _spieleScreenshots` is an array.

How can I get my array back in the `didReceiveData` method? Is this possible?

```
(void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {}
```

I use this to create the data:

NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.spieleScreenshots];

and this in the didRecieveData method:
NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

Now I get this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]:

Comment: You can't encode an array like that, use NSKeyed(Un)Archiver

Comment: Is _spieleScreenshots an NSArray or a plain C array? In the latter case: How exactly is it declared?

Comment: It is an NSMutableArray - @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray* spieleScreenshots;